# MySQL Joining three tables takes much time to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join, left-join

my below select query that joins three tables (products, descriptions, images) takes 9 seconds to return just 10 rows!

```
SELECT `products`.id, `products`.serialNumber, `products`.title, `descriptions`.description1, `descriptions`.description2, `descriptions`.description3, `descriptions`.description4,`products`.price,`products`.colors, `products`.category, `products`.available, `products`.status, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `images`.file_name ORDER BY `images`.id) AS images 
FROM `products` 
INNER JOIN `descriptions`
ON `products`.id = `descriptions`.product_id 
LEFT JOIN `images` 
ON `products`.id = `images`.product_id
WHERE `products`.status = 1 
GROUP BY `products`.id
ORDER BY `products`.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

so after some research, I have arrived to the below answer which contains joining two tables and takes just one second to return the 10 rows, how I can add to it the third table (descriptions)? thank you

```
SELECT  *,
    ( SELECT  group_concat(`images`.file_name)
        FROM  `images`
    ) AS images
FROM  `products`
JOIN  `images` ON `products`.id = `images`.product_id
WHERE `products`.status = 1 
GROUP BY `products`.id
ORDER BY `products`.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: When posting performance questions you should provide table definitions ,volumes, and explain plan. In most cases poor performance is down to poor indexing (or no indexing) hence the requirement for table definitions and explain plan. Timing may well be reasonable for volumes, BTW limit is limit on result set not read limit..

Comment: that's right but after some researches made, I found that the problem in my query.. for that I posted only the query... the correct answer down really decreased the executing time from 8 seconds to 1 second!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for better performance  be sure you have a composite index on  table products   columns

```
status, id
```

on table descriptions  and index on column

```
product_id
```

on table image an index on column

```
 product_id
```

Anyway you could join the 3 tables using a subquery for aggreagation and join  this subquery

```
    SELECT  *, my_images.aggr_images
    FROM  `products`
    INNER JOIN `descriptions` ON `products`.id = `descriptions`.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT product_id, group_concat(`images`.file_name) aggr_images 
            FROM  `images`
            GROUP BY product_id
        ) AS my_images on my_images.product_id = `products`.id
    WHERE `products`.status = 1 
    ORDER BY `products`.id DESC
    LIMIT 10
```